# 32 bit program won't run on 19.04 64 bit

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit

I use a CCS command-line compiler for PIC programming. I've been using it and upgrading it for over a decade, and I'm comfortable with it. I recently updated to Ubuntu 19.04 64 bit, and now the program fails with a Seg Fault.

All of my other 32-bit software seems to work fine, and CCS support says it should run in 64-bit, but they have provided little other support other than that. They don't even reply other than that one answer.

Is there any way that I can force the program to run using the 32-libs? I'm just assuming that might be the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here are the ldd results:

```
ldd ccsc.bin  
    linux-gate.so.1 (0xf7fcb000)  
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf7f85000)  
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf7f7f000)  
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf7d9f000)  
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7fcc000)
```

I have located all of these libraries in '/lib/i386-linux-gnu/' except **Linux-gate.so.1'**. I attempted **sudo apt-get -y install Linux-gate**
But it was not found.

Ok, so I learned Linux-gate is a virtual library and certainly not my problem. All dependencies appear to be installed. CCS will provide no help (I guess because I'm the only Linux user with a 64-bit machine) Any help from any of you would be appreciated. I'm converting my code to XC8, but that is a painful process.

Comment: Use `ldd` on the "CCS command-line compiler" to see which libraries it uses.

Comment: Thanks Waltinator,

Comment: I added the ldd results to my question.

Comment: Maybe try limiting the memory seen to 2G.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484016/setting-limit-to-total-physical-memory-available-in-linux

Comment: Another fix might be to run a 32 bit virtual machine and do your work there.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you are missing the x86 compatibility layer. To install it, you need to install some dependencies (IIRC the following):

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get -y install lib32z1 libc6-i386 lib32stdc++6 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5
```

There may be other libs you'd need to install, but these are probably the most popular.

Comment: I know I ran the dpkg --add architecture. And I thought I add the needed libs, but it appears 'lib32ncurses5' could not be found.